# How to add custom library xmlseclibs to zend2 framework?

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework

How to add custom library xmlseclibs to zend2 framework ?
.The main file xmlseclibs.php included 3 bellow  classes "XMLSecEnc.php","XMLSecurityDSig.php","XMLSecurityKey.php" .

I given `'xmlDigisign' => $vendorDir . '/xmlseclibs/src/xmlseclibs.php'`  in autoload_classmap . Also added `use xmlDigisign;` in my controller .`$objDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig();` . It returns error . How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You should not edit the autoload classmap manually but rather use composer's capability: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Personnaly, I would not copy/paste those classes into the vendor folder (keep it for composer only) but rather have a, say, opt folder.

- module
- opt

  - xmlseclibs

    - xmlseclibs.php
    - XMLSecEnc.php
    - XMLSecurityDSig.php
    - XMLSecurityKey.php
- vendor
- composer.json

Then inside of the composer.json, autoload  the file (https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/composer.json#L21):

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src/"
        },
        "files": ["opt/xmlseclibs/xmlseclibs.php"]
    }
}
```

Do not forget to refresh the autoloader once this is done (composer dump-autoload).

Hopefully this will help, any other question just ask!